# Можно ли посмотреть, что лежит в VBO

Tags: opengl

Мне нужно посмотреть, что находиться в VBO. Есть такая возможность в OpenGL? Вот часть кода, если он нужен:

```
    GLuint mVao;
    std::vector<GLuint> mBuffers;

    void GL::VAO::addVertexBufferObject(const std::vector<glm::vec3>& data)
    {
       GLuint vbo;
       glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
       glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
       glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, data.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), data.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
       glVertexAttribPointer(mBuffers.size(), 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, nullptr);
       mBuffers.push_back(vbo);
    }
```

Comment: Если вы сами положили и не знаете что там .. может быть вам нужен RenderDoc - программа для отладки и просмотра всего и вся.

Comment: Мне нужно это не для отладки. Я хочу построить нормали по тем данным, которые там лежат

Comment: Значит берите нормали до того как их туда положите ;-)